# When resizing a hash table how to point to the new array of buckets

Tags: arrays, c, struct, hashtable

When testing my code it seems as though when I am resizing my bucket array the `hash_table` struct is not pointing to my new resized hash table. Is this the route to take when resizing a hash table? Or instead of having `buck_array` being `hash_entry **` should it have been a `hash_entry *`

also `hash_key()` function gives the index in the bucket array based on `char *string`.

relevant structs:

```
typedef struct hash_entry_{
    char *string;
    void *data;
    struct hash_entry_ *next;
}hash_entry; 

typedef struct hash_table_{
    hash_entry ** buck_array;
    unsigned num_buckets;
} hash_table, *Ptrhash_table;
```

My resize function:

```
void resize_hash(Ptrhash_table table, int size) {
    unsigned int old_Bnum = table->num_buckets;
    table->num_buckets = size;
    int i;
    hash_entry *cur;

    hash_entry **new_arr = (hash_entry **)calloc(size, sizeof(hash_entry));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        new_arr[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= old_Bnum; i++) {
        while((table->buck_array[i]) != NULL){
            cur = table->buck_array[i];
            table->buck_array[i] = cur->next;

            cur->next = new_arr[hash_key(table, cur->string)];
            new_arr[hash_key(table, cur->string)] = cur;
        }
    }
    free(table->buck_array);
    table->buck_array = new_arr;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it is not pointing to your new array?  Could you provide a [mcve] that prints some debugging info and show us how that output differs from what it should be?

Comment: `calloc(size, sizeof(hash_entry));` should be `calloc(size, sizeof(hash_entry *));` , or ideally, `calloc(size, sizeof *new_arr);` And since it is `calloc`'d, the ensuing nullifying loop is pointless; they're all already null.

Comment: Simpler: `table->buck_array = realloc(table->buck_array, sizeof(*table->buck_array) * size); for (int i = old_Bnum; i < size; ++i) table->buck_array[i] = NULL;` (i.e.) Just resize the existing array.

Comment: _Side note:_ Use the same signedness/type for all of: `i/old_Bnum/num_buckets/size` (i.e.) `unsigned`